# missing proceed to checkout button in Magento 1.9.1

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9

I have a dev site almost ready and have noticed that in the cart page the proceed to checkout button is missing. I have posted a question with the developers of the template (JM_HAGA) I am using but have had no response. There is a similar post but no clear resolution.
Magento CE 1.9.1 
I have double checked I haven't disabled onepage as someone else mentioned this on another forum. I have double checked the cart.phtml for any changes to the original that was uploaded. No change there. There is a CHECKOUT button within the header and also within the cart pop up box but it really should not be missing from the cart page. The Paypal button is visible but I have other payment options so need to direct customers to Checkout.
Let me know if anyone has any ideas for me or let me know if you need further information and what info you need.

Comment: When I view a demo of the template used and compare the page source to my DEV site the following is missing <li>    <button type="button" title="Proceed to Checkout" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout" onclick="window.location='http://haga.demo.ubertheme.com/checkout/onepage/';"><span><span>Proceed to Checkout</span></span></button>
</li>
                                                            <li><a href="http://haga.demo.ubertheme.com/checkout/multishipping/" title="Checkout with Multiple Addresses">Checkout with Multiple Addresses</a>
</li>

Comment: I have just switched to default theme and button appears. Switched back no button again!

Comment: Ok went through each extension disabling and testing until I came across an extension for customers to add a comment to their order. This was affecting it. The developer of the extension is now looking into this issue now. May have to simply disable this extension for now until the developer can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with one of the extensions I had installed. I went through each add on and disabled and refreshed cache just to check. I came across the Customer comments extension which was causing the problem. This has now been disabled and I have notified the developer of the extension who is looking into it. Because I had installed many extensions in one go I had no idea until final testing of the site where I noticed the missing proceed to checkout button.